# Ms-access query to merge rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want a query to merge each of two rows meeting the following conditions in a large table:

1. `Surname`, `Name`, `FatherName` are duplicates
2. `1`, `2` contain "---" on one of the rows and `3`, `4` contain "---" on the other row

**Example data:**

```
Surname  Name   FatherName  Phone  Mobile   1     2     3     4
Smith    Alex   Nick        12345  00000   xxx   zzz   ---   ---
Smith    Alex   Nick        12345  00000   ---   ---   vvv   aaa
Jone     Mary   John        22222  11111   sss   eee   ---   ---
Pan      Peter  Peter       33333  22222   ttt   uuu   ---   ---
Bob      Nick   Nick        44444  77777   ---   ---   ppp   qqq
Mary     Maria  John        99999  00000   jjj   kkk   ---   ---
Mary     Maria  John        99999  00000   ---   ---   iii   ---
```

**Expected output:**

```
Surname  Name   FatherName  Phone  Mobile   1     2     3     4
Smith    Alex   Nick        12345  00000   xxx   zzz   vvv   aaa
Jone     Mary   John        22222  11111   sss   eee   ---   ---
Pan      Peter  Peter       33333  22222   ttt   uuu   ---   ---
Bob      Nick   Nick        44444  77777   ---   ---   ppp   qqq
Mary     Maria  John        99999  00000   jjj   kkk   iii   ---
```

Comment: Are all rows duplicated at most once, and aren't there any cases with all 4 fields filled in? The best approach certainly depends on that.

Comment: @Erik A Hello Eric, as you can see in my example not all rows have duplicates. My first try to clean the table is to find the rows that have duplicate base on 3columns.

Comment: that's not an answer to my questions... I ask if there can be more than 2 of a single row, and if there are no rows with valid values for all 4 fields you're interested in.

Comment: If there will be no more than 2 rows for each 'duplicate', looks like an aggregate query using Max() function should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple query:

```
Select
    Surname,  
    Name,
    FatherName,
    Phone,
    Mobile,
    Max(T.[1]) As [1],
    Max(T.[2]) As [2],
    Max(T.[3]) As [3],
    Max(T.[4]) As [4]
From
    YourTable As T
Group By
    Surname,  
    Name,
    FatherName,
    Phone,
    Mobile
```

Comment: @ColonelSoftware: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your sample data.
First with a self join I get the merged rows and then with UNION ALL for the unique rows:

```
SELECT t1.Surname, t1.Name, t1.FatherName, t1.Phone, t1.Mobile,
t1.[1], t1.[2], t2.[3], t2.[4]
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t1.Surname = t2.Surname AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.FatherName = t2.FatherName
AND (
  (t1.[1] <> '---' OR t1.[2] <> '---')
  AND 
  (t1.[3] = '---' AND t1.[4] = '---')
  AND 
  (t2.[3] <> '---' OR t2.[4] <> '---')
  AND
  (t2.[1] = '---' AND t2.[2] = '---')
)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename AS t2
  WHERE t1.Surname = t2.Surname AND t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.FatherName = t2.FatherName AND t1.[1] <> t2.[1]
)
```